# Consistent pre-save validation for findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to find a consistent way to validate some of the ids I am saving into an array.

Schema:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  otherIds: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Other'}]
});
```

A couple of update statements:

Update entire doc based on id

```
var update = {
  otherIds: someIds
};
MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, event, ...);
```

Lets just add to the otherIds set:

```
var update = {
  $addToSet: {
    otherIds: someId
  }
};
MyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, ...);
```

So as far as I know there are a few ways to validate those ids, but I have run into problems with all of them.

1. Use save middleware.  This does not work as save middleware is not called when using findAndUpdate commands.
2. Use findOneAndUpdate middleware.  This is probably the most promising as this middleware is going to be called in both cases.  However trying to extract the otherIds from the update statement is inconsistent, as each update statement is very different.  This seems fragile as anytime someone adds a new update statement they would potentially have to modify this middleware to accommodate a possibly different update statement.
3. Use validator.  I have tried using a validator and it works great for the first update, but is not run for the second update.  According to the docs, validators are only run for $set and $unset commands, and $addToSet does not fall into that category.

Are there any other options or anything I may have missed?

Comment: Why not use `findById()` and then `.save()` ?

Comment: Yup, sorry that is a good 4th option.  I would like to stay away from that as it not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

The one other solution would be to first call `findById(...)` and then `.save()` that document.

If you need to stick with `findByIdAndUpdate(...)`, you can also use [query middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) (requires mongoose >= 4)

```
schema.pre('update', function() {
  this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
});
```

However, the issue with that solution is that `this` is the query object, not the document, which isn't ideal for validation.

Comment: Would like to stay away from findById then save as that is not atomic. Don't see how query middleware will help, as I outline in the question already and you stated not ideal in that the update object is not consistent, across different update statements.

Comment: `save` after `findById`, doesn't it generate the duplicate key error on the _id?

Comment: No, this updates the document(s) matching the query object (`this`)

Comment: After some trial and error, I found that currently, findByIdAndUpdate won't trigger the pre `update` hook. However, it will trigger the `findOneAndUpdate` hook.